# Node server is getting down with error buffer.js:488 throw new Error('toString failed');

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, requestjs

We have an app build on nodejs (Server A), which is fetching data from another nodejs app(Server B) using REST API's.

Similarly for downloading files Server A make request on Server B and Server B fetches files from AWS S3 and pipes the data back to server A.

This system works perfectly and we are able to download files upto 1GB.

Issue is sometimes Server A crashes with below error:

```
    buffer.js:488
    throw new Error('toString failed');
    ^

Error: toString failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:488:11)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/www/sky/portal/node_modules/request/request.js:1145:39)
    at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/sky/portal/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Server A is calling server B using below code:

```
exports.downloadAsset = function(req, res, assetUrl, cb) {
  res.cookie('fileDownload', 'true');
  request(
    config.api.baseUrl + assetUrl
    ,
    function(error, response, body) {

    }
  ).pipe(res);
}
```

We are not sure from where app is getting crashed.
Please suggest.

Comment: do you have the code that calls the request module on server A?

Comment: @PeterGrainger, added request module in question.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @A_J?

Comment: Yes @Jeremy, we had  to modify our flow. We were streaming data from Server B to Server A, but now Server B is sending signed URL to Server A and file is being downloaded directly from S3 using that signed url.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution I used to sort above issue:
 I had to modify our flow. We were streaming data from Server B to Server A, but now Server B is sending signed URL to Server A and file is being downloaded directly from S3 using that signed url.